# DOMPDF output first page only

Tags: dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to convert HTML to a PDF file.

I only want to output the first page that DOMPDF generates. For example, if there is four pages worth of HTML, I want a PDF that has only the first of these four pages. The remaining three pages should be ignored or discarded.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432760/dom-pdf-generate-only-1-page-pdf-skip-remaining-content) states that:

> If you really need to render only the first page to a PDF that's a bit more difficult. Though technically possible to do this only with dompdf I'd actually be inclined to fully render the PDF then use an external library to pull out just the first page.

I want to do this with DOMPDF only, I do not want to use an external library.

How can I make DOMPDF generate a single page PDF only?